# JAVE Library for Mac

Tags: java, jave

I'm actually trying to launch my Unix code on my Mac.
I know that I have to build ffmpeg on my Mac.

I used a Github script for that :

[Script](https://github.com/markus-perl/ffmpeg-build-script)

My code :

```
package test1;
import it.sauronsoftware.jave.*;
import test1.MyFFMPEGExecutableLocator;

import java.io.*;
public class Test1 {
    public static void main (String[] zero) throws IllegalArgumentException, InputFormatException, EncoderException{
        File source = new File("/Users/Mokeight/Desktop/Test2.mp3");

        File target = new File("/Users/Mokeight/Desktop/target2.wav");

        System.out.println("START");

        AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
        EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();

        //codec de wav

        audio.setCodec("pcm_s16le");
        attrs.setFormat("wav");
        attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);

        //System.out.println(new MyFFMPEGExecutableLocator().toString());
        Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new MyFFMPEGExecutableLocator());


        encoder.encode(source, target, attrs);


        System.out.println("END");


    }
}
```

My second class is :

```
package test1;

import it.sauronsoftware.jave.FFMPEGLocator;

public class MyFFMPEGExecutableLocator extends FFMPEGLocator{
    @Override
    protected String getFFMPEGExecutablePath() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String path = "/Users/Mokeight/Desktop/ffmpeg_mac/ffmpeg-build/workspace/bin/ffmpeg" ;  
        return path;

    }
}
```

When i'm running that , i have this error :

```
START
Exception in thread "main" it.sauronsoftware.jave.EncoderException:   Metadata:
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:863)
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:713)
    at test1.Test1.main(Test1.java:27)
```

Please, help

Thanks !!

Comment: Maybe the `ffmpeg` file is not marked as executable. You can make it executable by running this command `chmod +x /Users/Mokeight/Desktop/ffmpeg_mac/ffmpeg-build/workspace/bin/ffmpeg`

Comment: Thanks for the help , it still change nothing, but i'm glad you help :D

Comment: Did you manage to get that custom FFmpeg executable working with Jave?